# Xcode 8.3.3 problems calling String.index(of:)

Tags: ios, xcode8

My Xcode, Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b), crashes when I try to find a substring. If I paste the following into an empty playground, it crashes:

```
import UIKit
let str = "abc"
str.index(of: "b")
```

I can't believe that Apple would let such a glaring bug through, so after some fruitless googling I assumed the problem was on my side. But deleting my Derived Data folder didn't help. Deleting and reinstalling Xcode didn't help.

Interestingly, if I remove the line "import UIKit" i get a compiler error instead of the crash:

```
Playground execution failed: error: MyPlayground.playground:2:8: error: argument labels '(of:)' do not match any available overloads
   str.index(of: "b")
       ^    ~~~~~~~~~

MyPlayground.playground:2:8: note: overloads for 'index' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (after: String.Index), (before: String.Index)
   str.index(of: "b")

   ^
```

So it seems that the compiler can't find the `index(of:)` method in String. But that is a standard method! I copy-pasted examples straight from Apples docs and from "The Swift Programming Language" and got the same error.

I still can't imagine that this is a bug in Xcode, so:

- Is there something else I should try?
- Is this a known bug?
- Is there some other reasonable way forward (I'm considering doing my string processing in an Objective C class just to get around this problem, for example)?

#### Crash Details (probably not important)

When I look at the crash log from the Playground, the crash seems to occur in `swift::TypeBase::getCanonicalType() + 23`, while attempting to recover from some other problem that occurred in `swift::TypeChecker::solveForExpression`.

In my project, it doesn't matter if I import a library or not: I get a segmentation fault at compile time. This is my test class:

```
class Bug {
    func foo() {
        let str = "abc"
        let _ = str.index(of: "b")
    }
}
```

I get a Swift Compiler Error, "Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11". Something happens in `swift::TypeChecker::solveForExpression() + 6229` which causes a call to `swift::constraints::ConstraintSystem::salvage` and eventually the error occurs in `swift::TypeBase::getContextSubstitutions(swift::DeclContext const*) + 1158`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `String.index(of:)` is new in Swift 4 and I should have been calling `String.characters.index(of:)` or `String.range(of:)` instead. I had forgotten the name of the function and did a quick net search, but Apple seems to have removed all documentation for Swift 3 (even though they haven't released an IDE with support for Swift 4 yet). The method names are quite similar.

I guess the crash was caused by some premature partial implementation of `index(of:)` in UIKit, and the compiler error I got in the playground was actually correct.